# Passing attributes to callback functions

Tags: php, function, callback

Is there a way we could pass attributes to callback functions called

```
// An example callback method

class MyClass {
    static function myCallbackMethod() {
        echo 'Hello World!';
    }
}

call_user_func(array('MyClass', 'myCallbackMethod'));
```

What if the function myCallbackMethod accepts certain attributes? How can I use call the function and also pass attribute values?

REF: http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.callable.php#example-75

Answer (score 0):

you can try this way, [call_user_func_array()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.call-user-func-array.php)

```
class foo {
    function bar($arg, $arg2) {
        echo __METHOD__, " got $arg and $arg2\n";
    }
}

// Call the $foo->bar() method with 2 arguments
$foo = new foo;
call_user_func_array(array($foo, "bar"), array("three", "four"));

output :- foo::bar got three and four
```